Generating stiff diagrams with different colors in R
I am trying to generate some stiff diagrams using an R package developed by USGS: https://pubs.usgs.gov/publication/ofr20161188. The figures are generating fine but I am having issues with coloring the individual stiff plots with different colors. You will see in the following example code that I am trying to group them into two color groups but the plot is applying a single color for all four stiff plots. Any fix around this issue would be appreciated. thanks in advance.
# Load required packages
require(smwrGraphs)
require(smwrData)

# prepare stiff diagram space
setSweave("stiffplot", 6, 6)
AA.lo <- setLayout(height=3.5, explanation=list(bottom=1.1))
setGraph(1, AA.lo)

# get the environmental data
data(MiscGW)

# convert to appropriate concentrations
PD <- transform(MiscGW, Ca.meq = conc2meq(Calcium, "calcium"),
                Mg.meq = conc2meq(Magnesium, "magnesium"),
                Na.meq = conc2meq(Sodium, "sodium"),
                Cl.meq = conc2meq(Chloride, "chloride"),
                SO4.meq = conc2meq(Sulfate, "sulfate"),
                HCO3.meq = conc2meq(Bicarbonate, "bicarb"))

PD$SS <- row.names(PD)

# Generate the plot
AA.pl <- with(PD, stiffPlot(cbind(Ca.meq, Mg.meq, Na.meq)
                            , cbind(Cl.meq, SO4.meq, HCO3.meq), ylabels=SS
                            , caption = "Stiff diagrams"
                            , Stiff= list(fill = c("#228B22", "#228B22", "#00688B", "#00688B"))
                            )
              )
setGraph("explanation", AA.lo)
addExplanation(AA.pl)

graphics.off()


it can be considered cheating but the only way i found, is to use the par function and create seperate plots below each other. The main problem is, that Stiffplot only takes one color in Stiff and colors to apply to all polygons. Therefore Stiff= list(fill = c("#228B22", "#228B22", "#00688B", "#00688B")) did not work!
#install.packages("remotes")
#remotes::install_gitlab("water/analysis-tools/smwrData", host = "code.usgs.gov")
#remotes::install_gitlab("water/analysis-tools/smwrGraphs", host = "code.usgs.gov")

library(smwrData)
library(smwrGraphs)
library(dataRetrieval)

# Prepare stiff diagram space
setSweave("stiffplot", 6, 6)
AA.lo <- setLayout(height=3.5, explanation=list(bottom=1.1))
setGraph(1, AA.lo)

# Get the environmental data
data(MiscGW)

# Check if necessary columns are available in the data
required_cols <- c("Calcium", "Magnesium", "Sodium", "Chloride", "Sulfate", "Bicarbonate")
if (!all(required_cols %in% colnames(MiscGW))) {
  stop("Missing one or more required columns in the MiscGW dataset")
}

# Convert to appropriate concentrations
PD <- transform(MiscGW, 
                Ca.meq = conc2meq(Calcium, "calcium"),
                Mg.meq = conc2meq(Magnesium, "magnesium"),
                Na.meq = conc2meq(Sodium, "sodium"),
                Cl.meq = conc2meq(Chloride, "chloride"),
                SO4.meq = conc2meq(Sulfate, "sulfate"),
                HCO3.meq = conc2meq(Bicarbonate, "bicarb"))

PD$SS <- row.names(PD)



# Set up the plotting layout
par(mfrow=c(6,1))  # Adjust margins for all plots

# First Stiff diagram
stiffPlot(
  cbind(PD$Ca.meq, PD$Mg.meq, PD$Na.meq)[1,],
  cbind(PD$Cl.meq, PD$SO4.meq, PD$HCO3.meq)[1,],
  ylabels = PD$SS[1],
  Stiff = list(fill = "#228B22")
)

# Second Stiff diagram
stiffPlot(
  cbind(PD$Ca.meq, PD$Mg.meq, PD$Na.meq)[2,],
  cbind(PD$Cl.meq, PD$SO4.meq, PD$HCO3.meq)[2,],
  ylabels = PD$SS[2],
  Stiff = list(fill = "#228B22")
)

# Third Stiff diagram
stiffPlot(
  cbind(PD$Ca.meq, PD$Mg.meq, PD$Na.meq)[3,],
  cbind(PD$Cl.meq, PD$SO4.meq, PD$HCO3.meq)[3,],
  ylabels = PD$SS[3],
  Stiff = list(fill = "#00688B")
)

# Fourth Stiff diagram with extra top margin
stiffPlot(
  cbind(PD$Ca.meq, PD$Mg.meq, PD$Na.meq)[4,],
  cbind(PD$Cl.meq, PD$SO4.meq, PD$HCO3.meq)[4,],
  ylabels = PD$SS[4],
  caption = "Stiff diagrams",
  Stiff = list(fill = "#00688B")
)

setGraph("explanation", AA.lo)
addExplanation(AA.pl)


# Close the graphics device
graphics.off()

and it will look like this:

ADD:
This is the place where it happens and all polygons are colored with the given color or grey by default. If you are really desperate about making the normal plot work, maybe you can change the function here to except multiple color values and iterate over them.

Because why not
So we can just adjust the function and make our own version that accepts a color vector and use it like this:
stiffPlot2 <- function(cations, anions, # the data matrices
                       Stiff=list(fill=NULL, outline="black",
                                  height=2/3, bar="black"), # the plot
                       yaxis.orient="table", yaxis.order="none",
                       xaxis.range=c(NA, NA),
                       ylabels="Auto", xlabels=7,
                       catlabels="Auto", anlabels="Auto",
                       xtitle = "Milliequivalents per liter",
                       ytitle = "", caption="", # labels and titles
                       margin=c(NA, NA, NA, NA), ...) {
  
  # [Previous code remains the same until xax definition]
  
  if(is.null(Stiff$fill)) {
    Stiff$fill <- rep("gray80", nrow(cations))
  } else if(length(Stiff$fill) == 1) {
    Stiff$fill <- rep(Stiff$fill, nrow(cations))
  } else if(length(Stiff$fill) != nrow(cations)) {
    Stiff$fill <- rep(Stiff$fill, length.out=nrow(cations))
  }
  
  if(dev.cur() == 1)
    setGD("StiffPlot")
  if(catlabels[1L] == "Auto") {
    catlabels <- colnames(cations)
    if(is.null(catlabels))
      catlabels <- paste("cat", seq(ncol(cations)))
  }
  if(anlabels[1L] == "Auto") {
    anlabels <- colnames(anions)
    if(is.null(anlabels))
      anlabels <- paste("an", seq(ncol(anions)))
  }
  
  Stiff <- modifyList(list(outline="black", height=2/3, bar="black"), Stiff)
  
  if(ylabels[1L] == "Auto") {
    ylabels <- rownames(cations)
    if(is.null(ylabels))
      ylabels <- format(seq(nrow(cations)))
  }
  
  xmax <- max(cations, anions, na.rm=TRUE)
  
  # Modified x-axis creation to use absolute values for labels
  if(any(is.na(xaxis.range))) {
    xax <- linearPretty(c(-xmax, xmax), labels=xlabels)
    # Modify the labels to show absolute values
    xax$labels <- abs(as.numeric(xax$labels))
  } else {
    xax <- linearPretty(xaxis.range, hard=TRUE, labels=xlabels)
    xax$labels <- abs(as.numeric(xax$labels))
  }
  
  yaxis.orient <- match.arg(yaxis.orient, c("table", "grid"))
  if(length(yaxis.order) == 1L)
    yaxis.order <- match.arg(yaxis.order, c("none", "ascending", "descending"))
  yax <- namePretty(ylabels, orientation=yaxis.orient, order=yaxis.order,
                    label.abbr=FALSE)
  ylev <- yax$labels
  y <- numericData(ylabels, ylev)
  margin <- setMargin(margin, yax=yax)
  par(mar=margin$margin)
  
  plot(0, 1, ylim = yax$range, xlim=xax$range, type = "n", axes = F,
       xlab="", ylab="")
  N <- length(y)
  x <- rep(0.0, N)
  pin <- par("pin")
  width <- pin[1L]
  height <- pin[2L]/N
  xrange <- par("usr")[c(1L, 2L)]
  Sbar <- Stiff$bar
  Stiff$bar <- "none"
  
  retval <- addStiff(x, y, width, height, cations, anions, Stiff, xaxis.range=xrange)
  
  Stiff$bar <- Sbar
  retval$explan$stiff$catlabels <- catlabels
  retval$explan$stiff$anlabels <- anlabels
  retval$explan$stiff$Stiff <- Stiff
  
  if(Stiff$bar != "none")
    abline(v=0, col=Stiff$bar, lwd=stdWt())
  
  renderY(yax, lefttitle=ytitle, left=list(ticks = FALSE, labels = TRUE,
                                           grid = FALSE, finegrid = FALSE,
                                           extend=FALSE),
          right=list(ticks = FALSE, labels = FALSE, grid = FALSE, 
                     finegrid = FALSE))
  renderX(xax, bottitle=xtitle, bottom=list(ticks = TRUE, labels = TRUE,
                                            grid = FALSE, finegrid = FALSE,
                                            extend = TRUE),
          top=list(ticks = FALSE, labels = FALSE, grid = FALSE, 
                   finegrid = FALSE), caption=caption)
  
  retval <- list(cations=retval$cations, anions=retval$anions,
                 yaxis.log=FALSE, yaxis.rev=FALSE, yaxis.lev=ylev,
                 xaxis.log=FALSE, explanation=retval$explan, margin=margin,
                 yax=yax, xax=xax)
  
  ck <- max(strwidth(c(retval$explanation$stiff$anlabels, retval$explanation$stiff$catlabels),
                     family="USGS", units="inches")) - .25
  if(ck > 0) {
    retval$explanation$stiff$width <- 2 + 2*ck
    retval$explanation$stiff$xaxis.range <- retval$explanation$stiff$xaxis.range * (1 + ck)
  }
  invisible(retval)
}

addStiff <- function(x, y, width, height,
                     cations, anions, # the data matrices
                     Stiff=list(fill=NULL, outline="black",
                                height=2/3, bar="black"), # the plot
                     xaxis.range=c(NA, NA),
                     catlabels="", anlabels="",
                     current=list(yaxis.log=FALSE, yaxis.rev=FALSE,
                                  xaxis.log=FALSE)) {
  
  # Set default fill colors if not provided
  if(is.null(Stiff$fill)) {
    Stiff$fill <- rep("gray80", nrow(cations))
  }
  
  y <- numericData(y, lev=current$yaxis.lev)
  y <- transData(y, current$yaxis.log, current$yaxis.rev,
                 current$ytrans, current$ytarg)
  x <- numericData(x, lev=current$xaxis.lev)
  x <- transData(x, current$xaxis.log, FALSE,
                 current$xtrans, current$xtarg)
  if(!is.matrix(cations))
    cations <- matrix(cations, nrow=1)
  if(!is.matrix(anions))
    anions <- matrix(anions, nrow=1)
  Miss <- apply(cbind(cations, anions), 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
  if(any(Miss)) {
    anions[Miss, ] <- NA
    cations[Miss, ] <- NA
  }
  Nobs <- length(Miss)
  if(Nobs != length(x))
    stop("length of x and y must match the number of observations in cations and anions")
  llcat <- ncol(cations)
  llan <- ncol(anions)
  usr <- par("usr")
  pin <- par("pin")
  xin <- pin[1L]/(usr[2L] - usr[1L])
  yin <- pin[2L]/(usr[4L] - usr[3L])
  xmax <- max(c(anions, cations), na.rm=T)
  if(any(is.na(xaxis.range))) {
    xmax <- max(pretty(c(0, xmax), 2))
    xaxis.range <- c(-xmax, xmax)
  }
  yvalues <- c((0:(llcat-1))/(llcat-1),((llan-1):0)/(llan-1)) - 0.5
  yvalues <-  yvalues / yin * Stiff$height * height
  ybar <- c(-.5, .5) / yin * height
  antmp <- anions[, seq(llan, by=-1), drop=FALSE]
  data <- cbind(-cations, antmp)/diff(xaxis.range) * width / xin
  xlabpos <- c(-width, width) / 2 / xin
  
  for(i in seq(Nobs)) {
    # Use the corresponding color for each polygon
    polygon(data[i,, drop=TRUE] + x[i], yvalues+y[i], 
            col=Stiff$fill[i],  # Use individual color from vector
            border=Stiff$outline, lwd=stdWt())
    
    if(Stiff$bar != "none")
      segments(x[i], ybar[1L]+y[i], y1=ybar[2L]+y[i], col=Stiff$bar, lwd=stdWt())
    
    if(catlabels[1L] != "") {
      text(rep(xlabpos[1L], llcat) + x[i], yvalues[1:llcat] + y[i],
           labels=catlabels, adj=0, family="USGS")
      revanlab <- rev(anlabels)
      text(rep(xlabpos[2L], llan) + x[i], yvalues[(llcat+1):(llcat+llan)] + y[i],
           labels=revanlab, adj=1, family="USGS")
      for(j in seq(llcat))
        segments(xlabpos[1L] + x[i] + strwidth(catlabels[j], family="USGS"),
                 yvalues[j] + y[i], data[i,j] + x[i],
                 lty="dotted", lwd=stdWt())
      for(j in 1:llan)
        segments(xlabpos[2L] + x[i] - strwidth(revanlab[j], family="USGS"),
                 yvalues[llcat+j] + y[i], data[i, llcat+j] + x[i],
                 lty="dotted", lwd=stdWt())
    }
  }
  
  cats <- rep(c(.65, .5), length.out=llcat)
  ans <- rep(c(.65, .5), length.out=llan)
  explan <- list(stiff=list(x=0, y=1, width=2, height=height,
                            cations=cats, anions=ans, Stiff=Stiff, catlabels=catlabels,
                            anlabels=anlabels, xaxis.range=c(-1, 1)))
  invisible(list(cations=cations, anions=anions, explan=explan))
}

library(smwrData)
library(smwrGraphs)
library(dataRetrieval)

# Prepare stiff diagram space
setSweave("stiffplot", 6, 6)
AA.lo <- setLayout(height=3.5, explanation=list(bottom=1.1))
setGraph(1, AA.lo)

# Get the environmental data
data(MiscGW)

# Check if necessary columns are available in the data
required_cols <- c("Calcium", "Magnesium", "Sodium", "Chloride", "Sulfate", "Bicarbonate")
if (!all(required_cols %in% colnames(MiscGW))) {
  stop("Missing one or more required columns in the MiscGW dataset")
}

# Convert to appropriate concentrations
PD <- transform(MiscGW, 
                Ca.meq = conc2meq(Calcium, "calcium"),
                Mg.meq = conc2meq(Magnesium, "magnesium"),
                Na.meq = conc2meq(Sodium, "sodium"),
                Cl.meq = conc2meq(Chloride, "chloride"),
                SO4.meq = conc2meq(Sulfate, "sulfate"),
                HCO3.meq = conc2meq(Bicarbonate, "bicarb"))

PD$SS <- row.names(PD)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))  # Adjust margins for all plots
# Generate the plot
with(PD, stiffPlot2(cbind(Ca.meq, Mg.meq, Na.meq)
                            , cbind(Cl.meq, SO4.meq, HCO3.meq), ylabels=SS
                            , caption = "Stiff diagrams"
                            , Stiff= list(fill = c("#228B22", "#228B22", "#00688B", "#00688B"))
)
)

# Set up the plotting layout


setGraph("explanation", AA.lo)
addExplanation(AA.pl)


# Close the graphics device
graphics.off()

And it will look like this (only positive labels now :)):


your code produces a negative left axis.

@ToNoY It's fixed now.

thanks, concentrations cannot be negative.

@ToNoY Oh yes, whatever. Merry Christmas to you! :)
